# Como faço o import da biblioteca que falta? Google Calendar API Python

Tags: python, api, google-calendar

Estou tentando fazer a inserção de eventos no Google agenda, via script Python, mas acho que falta uma biblioteca, pois quando rodo o script aparece o seguinte erro

```
name error named 'service' is not defined
```

Script que estou rodando

```
event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2020-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Brasil',
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Brasil',
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'},
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': False,
    'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
    ],
  },
}

event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
print('evento criado com sucesso')
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?? Por favor não exclui minha pergunta

Comment: Posta o código todo, pelo erro ta dizendo que o **service** não está declarado!

Answer (score 0):

Caso este seja seu código todo, está faltando carregar libraries e instanciar `service`

Algo como:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=<SUA_CREDENCIAL_AQUI>)
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) deles

Espero que ajude